# How to conditionally show/hide controls & sections in WordPress customizer?

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer

I have some custom sections and controls in the WordPress customizer, including a section where other sections can be turned on and off depending on what elements the user wants on the page.
When a section is turned off the options(which are in a separate section) need to be deactivated in the customizer and need to stay that way when it refreshes.

My setting for showing and hiding the controls is created in my customizer.php file:

```
$wp_customize -> add_setting('showcontactblock', array (
'default' => '',
'description' => '',
'section' => 'sectionsonoff',
'transport' => 'postMessage',
)); 
    
$wp_customize -> add_control( new Toggle_Switch_Custom_control( $wp_customize, 'showcontactblock', array(
'label' => 'Show Contact Block Options:',
'description' => __(''),
'section' => 'sectionsonoff',
'settings' => 'showcontactblock',
'type' => 'checkbox',
'priority' => 3,
)));
```

I have been reading a lot of Weston Ruter's information around doing this, in particular [this article about it](https://make.xwp.co/2016/07/24/dependently-contextual-customizer-controls/), the details in [gist](https://gist.github.com/westonruter/2c1e87e381ca0c9a3dcb1e3a61a9eb4d) and [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257129/deactivate-sections-panels-when-the-customizer-finishes-loading/257132#257132) to another question.

Based on this I've attempted to use Weston's method in js which I have enqueued at customize_controls_enqueue_scripts :

```
( function( api ) {
    'use strict';

    api( 'showcontactblock', function( setting ) {
        var isContactBlockDisplayed, contactBlockSettingValueToControlActiveState;

        
        isContactBlockDisplayed = function() {
            return 'blank' !== setting.get();
        };

        contactBlockSettingValueToControlActiveState = function( control ) {
            var setActiveState = function() {
                control.active.set( isContactBlockDisplayed() );
            };

            control.active.validate = isContactBlockDisplayed;

            setActiveState();

            setting.bind( setActiveState );
        };

        api.control( 'contactemail', contactBlockSettingValueToControlActiveState );
        api.control( 'contactphone', contactBlockSettingValueToControlActiveState );
    } );

}( wp.customize ) );
```

My setting that should turn the controls on and off is 'showcontactblock' and I'm trying to show/hide 'contactemail' and 'contactphone'.
This code is not throwing any errors, but it's also not doing anything so I'm a bit stumped as to where I am going wrong, it's probably something really obvious!

Any suggestions would be a great help, thanks!